# SDcard mounts fine automatically, but has wrong fstype when mounting manually

Tags: mount, fstab

I'm attempting to mount the sdcard of a raspberry pi as user in an Ubuntu system.
If I just plug in the card, it mounts fine, but as root.
So I tried mounting it via fstab, but fstab doesn't seem to recognise the filesystem type.
The following line:
`/dev/mmcblk0p2    /media/benedict/raspi    ext4   nonauto,rw,user 0 0`

gives me ye olde "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock etc" error.
I've tried ext2 and ext3 as well as vfat with the same result, although that thing really should be ext4, though if I do fdisk -l, the type of the partition is simply shown as "Linux".

EDIT: following a comment, I ran blkid, and it does in fact show as ext4.

So, how comes that the thing mounts fine by default, but not when I try it myself?

Comment: When it mounts by itself, if you run `blkid` it should show you a `type=` which should be how it is formatted.

Comment: Yeah, that shows ext4. Not very surprising, but good to have definite confirmation.

Comment: One other thing I can think of that might help is to run the command `mount` with nothing after it after the SDCard is mounted and look at the options it mounted it with (they appear in parenthesis).  Manual mount might require a specific option.  But this is very strange to me.